# What should I use for Eclipse Databinding

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, javabeans, windowbuilder

I'm getting back into java programming after a long absence. I'm struggling with WindowBuilder's Swing Automatic Databinding Wizard. I got a bean working and the Wizard ran, but it had dependencies for org.jdesktop.beansbinding.. While poking around to find the jars I'm seeing few posts, and those are a decade old. After playing with jars for a couple of hours with no luck I'm convinced that I'm going down the wrong path. Despite a couple days of poking around for a decent tool I'm finding very little. What tools/wizards are good to use if I want to auto-bind data objects to field widgets in Eclipse?

Comment: See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html (use WindowBuilder to design the UI and in the Java editor add the binding to the widgets). Unfortunately, [asking to recommend a tool is off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Got you on the recommend prohibition. I actually had gone through the Vogella posting in some detail. However, as far as I can tell it is relying on hand coding all of the bindings. Did I miss something? The WindowBuilder Swing Wizard creates the interface components, the setters/getters and the bindings themselves, which is timesaving. However, the code relies on org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup (and three others.) I located the jar, added it to the build but it still didn't recognize. Is there something in the Vogella regarding wizards that I missed?

Comment: Figured it out. Having better success with the SWT Designer JFACE Automatic Databinding wizard. Wish I understood why the Swing designer JAR dependencies were so old and difficult to locate. But the SWT is getting me further.

Comment: Please file an issue at https://eclipse.org/eclipse/windowbuilder to have the old jar issue fixed.